# htaccess 2 mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, xampp

I am a beginner in .htaccess can any one help me with this?

//my  .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /alumini/profile.php?username=$1
```

//with the above i can redirct the url

**localhost/alumini/profile.php?username=name**

to

**localhost/alumini/name**

but i also want to hide **loacalhost/alumini/index.php** to **loacalhost/alumini**

> in simple ....
>
> i want an htaccess code to hide the index page also i need to convert
>
> **localhost/alumini/profile.php?username=name**
>
> to
>
> **localhost/alumini/name**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first request is a rewrite, not a redirect. Your second is a redirect. For the re-write, the following rule should do the trick (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^localhost/alumini/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /alumini/profile.php?username=$1
```

The regular expression inside the brackets matches one or more upper or lowercase letters and nothing else, and the value of the match is passed to $1. You may need to change the regular expression depending on the format of your usernames.

and for the index.php redirect (to remove the index.php where it exists):

```
Redirect 301 /alumini/index.php http://localhost/alumini
```

The 301 represents the fact that the page has moved permanently, and is better for SEO as only the non index.php page will be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^localhost/alumini/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /alumini/profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^localhost/alumini$ /alumini/index.php
```

Comment: Your second rule is not going to prevent people from visiting alumni/index.php - it needs to be redirected. Rewrite just means that people visiting alumni/ will be shown alumni/index.php which happens by default anyway.